# How to create a numbered list inside a table with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, list, numbers

I'm executing this type of code inside a table.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
 echo "" . $row['id'] . "";
 echo "" . $row['name'] . "";
 echo "" . $row['car'] . "";
  }
```

Which works great and gives me a numbered list (1 Mike Volvo, 2 Mike Ford) for example. The problem is that I now have multiple users in the same table so there are gaps in the list where someone else's entry is since i'm using auto incremented ID for numbers.

So assuming I have 5 entries I obviously want it to be 1-5 but right now its 5-30-45-65 or whatever.

Anyway I looked around for a solution and I found `$number = 1; $number++;` to be effective and it kind of works and gives me a 1-5 list independent of whatever the ID's are.

The problem is that when I reverse the list using `ORDER BY xxx desc` the last entry becomes 1 and the first entry becomes 5. But I always want the first entry to remain 1 and the last entry to be 5.

Do you have any ideas on how to create this function using PHP?

Comment: Using `$number++` should work fine regardless of the mysql query. Show that code.

Comment: If you want to go from 1-5 (or how ever many rows exist) and only increment when the UserId changes, check my answer. I Think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: The problem is that when I run "order by xx DESC" the last entry in my database is displayed first and therefore the $number++; $number function assigns it a one when it should assign it a five since it's the latest entry in the database.

The function works as intended whe you order by asc. 

To clarify what I want: assume my database entries is from January, February, March, April and May 2014. Then January should always be numbered 1 but right now it gets number 5 if I run order by desc using that function.

Comment: If you want to have for example months, why don't you have another column with month number (from 1 to 12)? If you do it this way you will have month number regardless of ordering. If it's not solution, you should change your question and show table structure and display in details what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 4):

You need to simple user `$number` as you mentioned as in the following code

```
 $number = 1;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
    echo $number;
    echo "" . $row['name'] . "";
    echo "" . $row['car'] . "";
    ++$number;
 }
```

Even if in your SQL you have `order by` it does not matter in that case.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question... You are on the right track using the following code...

```
$LastId ='';
$number = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  if($LastId != $row['id']){
    $number++;
  }  
  echo $number;
  echo "" . $LastId = $row['id'] . "";
  echo "" . $row['name'] . "";
  echo "" . $row['car'] . "";
 }
```

So... 
If the 'id' isn't the same as the last 'id' (not the same user) it will increment it by 1. Otherwise it will stay the same.

Hope this is what you looking for and helps.

Answer (score -1):

Although this is pretty trivial in php, I would not use php for it. You can easily do this in html:

```
echo "<ol>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<li>" . $row['name'] . $row['car'] . "</li>";
}
echo "</ol>";
```